# Invalid Credentials when accessing Google API for Shopping

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client, google-shopping-api

I'm trying to use the [google-api-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) gem to access the [Google Search API for Shopping](https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/).  Unfortunately, I can't seem to authenticate despite creating an access_token through the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

Here is my code:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.access_token = "<MY_CONSOLE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
client.authorization.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/shoppingapi"

shopping = client.discovered_api("shopping", "v1")
response = client.execute(api_method: shopping.products.list,
                          parameters: { source: "public" })
```

When I view `response.data`, I see an error message though:

```
#<Google::APIClient::Schema::Shopping::V1::Products:0x809d6e14 DATA:{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"authError", "message"=>"Invalid Credentials", "locationType"=>"header", "location"=>"Authorization"}], "code"=>401, "message"=>"Invalid Credentials"}}>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I figure it out minutes after posting.  I'll share what worked for anyone else who has the same question.

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(authorization: nil)
shopping = client.discovered_api("shopping", "v1")
response = client.execute(key: "<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>",
                          api_method: shopping.products.list,
                          parameters: { source: "public", country: "US" })
```

Comment: So many thanks for that answer that really helped me, but didn't you mean API Server Key by "Access Token" ?